# In AWS App Runner, how does one roll back to old revision

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecr, amazon-app-runner

What are the ways how one can roll back the App Runner service to the previous revision?

We use a simple GitHub Actions workflow to build and upload a new docker image to the ECR registry.

How can I select an old image in ECR and upload this instead (rolling back revision)?

Answer (score 1):

I'm also interested in this issue. It seems that when you create an app runner app with a specific image tag and that's it you cannot choose which version to deploy. You either have to amend the service change the Container image URI to the previous image